Start MariaDb on Windows without opening a new window
I am trying to run mysqld from a batch script to run mariadb without launching a new window. I'm running this when Windows launches.
Here is my script:
@echo off

set mariadb_home=C:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.6.5\bin

if not exist "%mariadb_home%\" (
    echo The specified MARIADB directory does not exist: %mariadb_home%
    exit /b 1
)

rem run mariadb in background
cd /d %mariadb_home%
start /b "" "mysqld"

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Failed to start services
    exit /b 1
)

exit /b 0

Currently this method works for my other services, (php-cgi and nginx), but for mariadb I have a new window showing:
2024-06-04 13:47:19 0 [Note] mysqld (server 10.6.5- MariaDB) starting as process 15096...

How can I make MariaDb run without opening another window. The flag /B option with start seems not to be working.

Open a Command Prompt window, type start /?, press the [ENTER] key, and read the output. You should notice that the option /B does not in any way mention, or suggest, running something in the background.

"Launches the application without creating a window." Are you sure ?

Positive; where is the word background used? The batch file you have started is running inside a Command Prompt window, all the /B option is doing is running mysqld in the same window rather that a new one.

Exactly that's the problem, they MUST running in the same window, but no. mysqld open a new terminal to write "starting as process 15096...".

That is not in the background, and your question is specific.

Try mysqld -D rather than using the start command.

I have rewrote your question to actually reflect your previous comment, and to remove all mention of background processes. It appears to me however that you are not directly starting the MariaDb service. You are running mysqld in the same window, but that is itself launching another process in the separate window. That is not the fault of your script, more a lack of understanding of how the process works.

Ok, first thanks for helping me (writing and replying). But everything you told me, I knew, maybe not explicitly like I said. But this sentence was perhaps a little too much "That is not the fault of your script, more a lack of understanding of how the process works" with an ounce of judgment. Could you shed some light on my lack of knowledge on how a process works? Because for me right now: my script executes mysqld , mysqld executes a process to start mariadb which therefore opens in a new window, the question is how to make all of this transparent?

The point I was making is that there is no problem with your script, and therefore your question is not suited for this particular platform. What you are wanting at the moment is information on what happens when you run mysqld, and that, as a software related question, may be better suited to SuperUser. Technically we do not provide a howto, or code writing service, we only help you to fix a problem with your script, (and that is functioning as written).

I should also say, as this is intended to be run at launch, that this could probably be preformed as SYSTEM from Windows Task Scheduler. I should also metion that 'services', (if that's what those really are), are generally run and handled using sc.exe, so you may wish to look at the output from %SystemRoot%\System32\sc.exe /? too. Of course you could have used the --install or --install-manual option to ensure that it was a service.

Appreciate @Compo, thanks i'll try to investigate

Why not install as a service? It will be "transparent" and should start automatically every time windows launch.

Exactly the same as you would start any other command line program with hidden Window
For example
powershell "start mysqld.exe -Args \"--console\" -WindowStyle Hidden"

This answer already has the right invocation, you just need to apply it to mysqld.exe or mariadbd.exe
